# При использовании Telethon выбрасывает из всех аккаунтов telegram?

Tags: python, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import time

API_ID = 
API_HASH = ''

client = TelegramClient('session_name', API_ID, API_HASH)
```

Я использую телеграм-аккаунт через библиотеку Telethon. Когда я запускаю программу, она запрашивает проверочные коды для входа, успешно запускается сессия, а через несколько
секунд этот аккаунт выбрасывает со всех устройств, на которых он запущен.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?